# Voronoi polygons tool not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, voronoi-thiessen

So I've been trying to build up some Voronoi diagram out of my point dataset but I can't seem to get it to work.

When I try it on QGIS 3.4 I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/VoronoiPolygons.py",
>   line 166, in processAlgorithm self.tr('There were no polygons
>   created.'))
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: There were no polygons created

If I try it on QGIS Mac if it makes a difference. Could use PostgreSQL if needed.

Comment: Is the error depending on your data?

Comment: @Mesa what do you mean? I thought voronoi polygons could be built out of any point geometry

Comment: just to go sure there is no issue with your data i would suggest to check if it works with other data

Comment: @Mesa I'm not sure what kind of issue you are talking about, the layer works fine